# GetLowestPricedOffersForSKU failed processing arguments

Tags: amazon-mws

I have a slight issue when trying to call GetLowestPricedOffersForSKU, I get the response :

> Failed processing arguments of org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata

I can call other functions in the Product Api and they work fine, just get the above error on this function.

I have looked round the net for the answer but can't find anything that is related to this, does anybody have any idea why I'm getting this ?

By the way it all works fine in the MWS Scratchpad !

Comment: which client library is used?

Answer (score 5):

Posting in case anyone else comes to this and is as confused as I was. There is a fundamental difference with how nearly all Amazon MWS requests work except this particular one. All other requests technically accept the parameters as query parameters instead of POST data. The scratchpad even suggests this is how it is actually working (although the MWS Scratchpad actually sends the data as Post Data Fields also).

Comment: And how this one behaves?

Answer (score 2):

MWS needs the POST data passed as form params instead of as a query string for some operations. Otherwise, it pukes a `Failed processing arguments of org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata` style `400 Bad Request` error for some operations such as this one (`GetMyFeesEstimate` is another that suffers from this).

For instance, if you did the following POST request in Guzzle 6 then you'd likely get the error:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01/?AWSAccessKeyId=YOURAWSACCESSKEY&Action=GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN&SellerId=YOURSELLERID&MWSAuthToken=amzn.mws.fghsffg-4t44e-hfgh-dfgd-zgsdbfe5erg&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2017-07-09T15%3A45%3A18%2B00%3A00&Version=2011-10-01&Signature=bCasdxXmYDCasdaXBhsdgse4pQ6hEbevML%2FJvzdgdsfdy2o%3D&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&MarketplaceId=ATVPDKIKX0DER&ASIN=B007EZK19E');
```

To fix this you'd submit it as form data as in this [Guzzle 6](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html?highlight=post#form-params) example:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01', [
    'form_params' => [
        'AWSAccessKeyId' => 'YOURAWSACCESSKEY',
        'Action' => 'GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN',
        'SellerId' => 'YOURSELLERID',
        'MWSAuthToken' => 'amzn.mws.fghsffg-4t44e-hfgh-dfgd-zgsdbfe5erg',
        'SignatureVersion' => 2,
        'Timestamp' => '2017-07-09T15%3A45%3A18%2B00%3A00',
        'Version' => '2011-10-01',
        'Signature' => 'bCasdxXmYDCasdaXBhsdgse4pQ6hEbevML%2FJvzdgdsfdy2o%3D',
        'SignatureMethod' => 'HmacSHA256',
        'MarketplaceId' => 'ATVPDKIKX0DER',
        'ASIN' => 'B007EZK19E',
    ]
]);
```

Comment: If I remove the params from the URL (and only have them in Post Fields) Amazon complains about missing parameters. If I leave them in the URL AND include them in Post Fields, the org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata error persists.  Any ideas?

Comment: thanks , this saved me. So crazy to think that a company as big as Amazon can't follow his own documentation!

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. Hope it will help someone.

```
<?php

    require_once('.config.inc.php');

    // More endpoints are listed in the MWS Developer Guide
    // North America:
    $serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01";
    // Europe
    //$serviceUrl = "https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01";
    // Japan
    //$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.jp/Products/2011-10-01";
    // China
    //$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com.cn/Products/2011-10-01";


     $config = array (
       'ServiceURL' => $serviceUrl,
       'ProxyHost' => null,
       'ProxyPort' => -1,
       'ProxyUsername' => null,
       'ProxyPassword' => null,
       'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
     );

     $service = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Client(
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            APPLICATION_NAME,
            APPLICATION_VERSION,
            $config);


     // @TODO: set request. Action can be passed as MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetLowestPricedOffersForSKU
     $request = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetLowestPricedOffersForSKURequest();
     $request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);
     $request->setMWSAuthToken(MWSAUTH_TOKEN);
     $request->setMarketplaceId(MARKETPLACE_ID);
     $request->setSellerSKU($sellerSKU);
     $request->setItemCondition($ItemCondition);
     // object or array of parameters
     invokeGetLowestPricedOffersForSKU($service, $request);


      function invokeGetLowestPricedOffersForSKU(MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Interface $service, $request)
      {
          try {
            $response = $service->GetLowestPricedOffersForSKU($request);

            echo ("Service Response\n");
            echo ("=============================================================================\n");

            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            $dom->loadXML($response->toXML());
            $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
            $dom->formatOutput = true;
            echo $dom->saveXML();
            echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $response->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");

         } catch (MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Exception $ex) {
             echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
             echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
             echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
             echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
             echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
             echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
             echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
         }
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi Paul,

Thanks for the info, I will give it a go and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

As @eComEvoFor stated, for this particularly method, Amazon demands you specify the params in the body of the request. In node.js using axios library you can do this:

```
const paramsSorted = {}
Object.keys(params)
  .sort()
  .forEach((key) => {
    paramsSorted[key] = params[key]
  })
const data = new URLSearchParams(paramsSorted)
url = urljoin(this.marketplace.url, this.api, this.api.Version)
const response = await axios.post(url, data)
```